# $X$ is an infinite set with the co-finite topology. Is $X$ locally connected?

Tags: general-topology

> We have a topological space $X$ with the co-finite topology. We assume that $X$ has an infinite amount of elements.

I already proved that $X$ is a connected space and now I would also like to check if it is locally connected. To do this I thought of trying to prove that any open set $U \subset X$ is connected, however I run into trouble. If $U$ is not connected we have $U = V \cup W$, with $V, W$ open in the subspace topology and $V \cap W = \emptyset$. If $V$ and $W$ are infinite sets we are done. However, Since $V,W$ are open in the subspace topology we have $V = U \cap X_1$ with $X_1 \subset X$. But the intersection of two infinite sets does not have to be infinite, so I'm not sure if these sets are indeed infinite. I tried coming up with counterexamples (for example taking $X = \mathbb{N}$) but they did not work either.

A hint or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: If $Y \subset X$, can you describe the subspace topology on $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple proof: every open set is infinite in $X$. Let consider the open set $U$ in $X$. The subspace topology on $U$ is also the cofinite topology over $U$, so $U$ is connected. Therefore every open set over $X$ is connected.